# Is there a word for "quick and precise"?

Tags: word-request

I am asking if there are any single words that mean "quick and precise", what I mean is that once somebody delivers exactly what I want and instantaneously.

I was thinking of "swift".

Which means:

> happening quickly or promptly.

But that is only part of what I want, I also need it to be precise.

Example usage in a sentence:

> My friend submits all his papers quickly and precisely.

Comment: When asking for a word, it is recommended that you supply an example sentence where this word would be used. The fact that you posted the answer only 30 minutes later suggests that you posted a self answer, nothing wrong with that. But there is no link. There is no attribution, you don't explain why *expeditious* fits. Why is "**The courier *promptly* / *punctually* or  *efficiently* delivered the parcel**” less acceptable?

Comment: Have you checked a bilingual dictionary (assuming that a word meaning quick and precise exists in your language)?

Comment: It's going to depend on the context. For example, if you were applying it to somebody's maths ability or ability to solve puzzles you would use a different word to if you were talking about a company's ability to deliver their product.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I edited my question.

Comment: How does one *submit* a paper *precisely*? *Sorry I had to reject your paper. You submitted it imprecisely!* That has no discernable meaning. You may want to reconsider your example sentence. Are you saying he submits his precisely written papers quickly? That is different from submitting them precisely and quickly.  **Succinct** is the word that first came to mind to mean quickly and precisely but *succinct* cannot always be applied to actions.  It is mostly limited to written and spoken communication.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther - succinct is 'brief & to the point', not 'quick'

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther - I'm merely trying to prevent the OP from being mis-directed. You cannot assume anyone's ability to distinguish nuance of meaning if you don't tell them. Your comment implies succinct to be a viable alternative. It is not. Succinct can apply to actions… just not this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider a word you already used in a quote - *prompt*. It means *carried out or performed without delay*. A similar alternative would be *timely*.

You can't really use a word like 'precision' because you are not talking about the content or quality of his work, but rather *the manner in which he submits it*. It can be submitted in a prompt or timely manner, but only the person considering the work can say if it is 'precise' or not.

Although these word choices might not fully convey what you want, they do suggest that *care* was taken. The problem with most synonyms of 'quick' is that they can suggest *haste* - that less care was taken. If you choose the right word to convey the right kind of speed, it may go without saying that it was satisfactory in other ways.

- My friend submits all his papers promptly.
- My friend submits all his papers in a timely fashion.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for something along the lines of **[alacrity](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alacrity)**.

It doesn't convey 'precision', but you can't submit a paper 'with precision'.
You could deliver one quickly & with a noticeable eagerness.

> My friend submits his papers with alacrity.

There's 'promptitude' but that sounds like you've been reading too much Dickens. Alacrity would at least make it as far as Harry Potter. It's still a bit stiff & formal, but at least it's *perky* and has no real negative connotation like the [now deleted] mention of 'expediency'.